Problem 2.13 from Hayt "Engineering Circuit Analysis" 8th edition
Here is practice problem 2.13 (p27) from Hayt's "Engineering Circuit Analysis" 8th edition.
"A 500 ft long 24 AWG soft copper wire is carrying a current of 100mA. What is the voltage dropped across the wire?"
The problem is preceded by the following table:

From the table, since our wire is only 500 ft long, resistance is going to be 25.7/2 = 12.85 ohm.
Hence, voltage drop is 12.85 × 0.1 = 1.285 V, but correct answer is 3.26 V. What am I missing?

They've erroneously used the figure for 28 AWG.
$$ \Delta V = 65.3 \times \frac {500}{1000} \times 0.1 = 3.265 \ \text V $$

Thank you! This is simply impressive how you caught it!

Well ... the other thing I checked was that they weren't using a loop - 500' out and 500' back. Don't forget to accept an answer to mark you post solved.
